# SCP through ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, scp, ssh-tunnel

```
ssh abc@202.221.23.87 -p 22724 -L 12345:172.21.33.51:18081
```

I openned the tunnel successfully and I tried on my localhost:

```
scp -P 12345 abc@127.0.0.1:/testfuel_20140714.zip .
```

But it's not working. It showed nothing. How to make `scp` works? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be creating the tunnel on localhost. Are you trying to download or upload a file?

```
ssh -p 22724 -L 12345:localhost:18081 abc@202.221.23.87
```

Comment: I am trying to download a zip file.

Comment: Should be fine then. Try adding the -v argument to your scp command to find out if you see a problem. Also check /var/log/messages on source/destination.